# Many to many relationships doesn't shown in JSON. Spring + JPA

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jpa

The relationships works fine, the tables are created and the data is inserted correctly. But when page loads in browser, many to many relationships doesn't shown.

[image: Many to many relationships doesn't shown]

But professions are not null:
[image]

Here is my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User  {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "login", nullable = true, length = 50)
private String login;

@Column(name = "pass", nullable = true, length = 50)
private String password;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String name;

....

public User() {
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="worker_profession", joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id_profession", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private Set<Profession> profession;

public Set<Profession> getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(Set<Profession> profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}
```

...

```
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profession")
public class Profession {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "profession_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String professionName;

public Profession() {
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProfessionName() {
    return professionName;
}

public void setProfessionName(String professionName) {
    this.professionName = professionName;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "profession")
private Set<User> users;

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

}
```

in UserController.class I have:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
 ...
}
```

So, where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: in User class replace this @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  with this @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Nope... Still nothing... :(

Comment: why not debug it ? you know, work out whether the data is returned from the JPA API call first, and then if it is you debug the JSON conversion ...

Comment: try insert new data your old data not incude profession datas

Comment: Only after I deleted all other entities, JSON showed me this relationships...  It seems like some conflict... Anyway, thanks everyone :)